# Crm 2013 plugin doesn't have post or pre image

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

I have been working on an existing plugin. It was running normally but needed to have som values adjusted.
Now i have adjusted the values and updated plugin through plugin registration tool. But now for some reason the postimage and preimage are blank.

Im running Crm 2013
!context.PostEntityImages.Contains("PostImage") is true every time.
Plugin step:
Message: update
Primary Entity: opportunity
Filtering Attributes: est. close date
run in users context: calling user
Execution Order: 1
Event pipeline stage of execution: Post-operation
Execution Mode: Synchronous
Deployment: Server

i haven't made any changes to the code before this check. So i think it must be either the build or the update that has problems.
I know the plugin runs, it just ends up in the no PostImage log everytime.
I checked that there is no PreImage data either.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Comment: did you register the image or not?

Comment: Adding to Guido's comment, can you double check the image names? post a screenshot if possible?

Comment: Everything was already set up and running, i only updated the assembly with a change to the datetime calculations that was done in the plugin.
i will try to check out the images when i get to work.

Comment: Both images where missing.
I have seen this plugin run and it worked. So i have no idea if the images where deleted during update or if it ran differently before or what.
Adding pre and post images worked.
Thank you for the answers.